Incompatible shape Keras Autoencoder
I'm relatively new and am trying to build an autoencoder for anomaly detection on an unlabelled dataset that only contains categorical columns.
The error I get is:
Incompatible shapes: [64,1,5346] vs. [64]
     [[{{node gradient_tape/compile_loss/huber/BroadcastGradientArgs_2}}]] [Op:__inference_one_step_on_iterator_109439]

I'm guessing it's related to the target output and the output of the model itself?
What am I doing wrong?
Here is my code with some sample categorical data:

# Define the number of rows
num_rows = 1000

# Define the categories for each column
categories = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

# Create a dictionary to hold column data
data = {}

# Generate random categorical data for each column
for i in range(10):
    column_name = f'Column_{i+1}'
    data[column_name] = np.random.choice(categories, size=num_rows)

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#encode labelled data to embed
X_train_enc = []
for column in df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns:
    label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
    train_enc = label_encoder.fit_transform(df[column])
    X_train_enc.append(train_enc)

#embed and generate input layer
in_layers = []
em_layers = []
for i in range(len(X_train_enc)):
    n_labels = len(unique(X_train_enc[i])) 
    output_dim = n_labels // 2
    in_layer = Input(shape=(1,))
    em_layer = Embedding(n_labels, output_dim)(in_layer)
    in_layers.append(in_layer)
    em_layers.append(em_layer)

merge = concatenate(em_layers)

#encoder
encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
    Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    Dense(5, activation='relu'),
])(merge)

#decoder
decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
    Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    Dense(merge.shape[2], activation='linear'),
])(encoder)

autoencoder = tf.keras.Model(inputs = in_layers, outputs = decoder)

# Compile the model
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

autoencoder.fit(X_train_enc, X_train_enc, epochs = 50, batch_size = 64, verbose = 2)


You're absolutely correct! The error "Incompatible shapes: [64,1,5346] vs. [64]" indicates a mismatch between the expected output shape and the actual output shape of your autoencoder.In your case, you're trying to use the same data for both input and target (reconstruction) in your autoencoder, which is typical for autoencoder setups. However, the way you're passing the data to the fit() function is incorrect.

In the fit() function, you're passing X_train_enc as both x (input) and y (target), which is leading to the shape incompatibility error. Instead, you need to pass the input data (X_train_enc) as x, and a copy of the input data (X_train_enc.copy()) as y, because in autoencoder, the target is the same as the input.autoencoder.fit(X_train_enc, X_train_enc.copy(), epochs=50, batch_size=64, verbose=2)
